# Getting value from list in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a simple script in Python, that creates a list of 10000 instances of `test` class. Then I'm looping through every element in the list and changing value of variable `x` to random string generated using `id_generator` method.

```
import string
import random


def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

class test:
    x = None
    y = None

d = test

lista = [d] * 10000

w = 0
while (w < 10000):
    lista[w].x = id_generator()
    w = w + 1

print(lista[3].x)
print(lista[40].x)
print(lista[1999].x)
```

Why do I get 3 same values on the output? Shouldn't I get 3 different values generated using `id_generator()`

Comment: Because you got list of 10000 _references_ for the test _class_. To create list like this: `lista = [test() for _ in xrange(10000)]`. While loop is ugly too, replace it with for in...

Comment: `lista[1] is lista[1493]` returns `True`. That is because you create only a single object that is 10000 times in your list.

Comment: I downvoted because you "should have understood" what this code `d = test; lista = [d] * 10000` is supposed to do.

Comment: Yes, that is a single object, but then I'm changing the value of x in one of its instance. Does it change the value of all of the objects in the list? Putting `print(lista[w].x)` inside the loop gives me 10000 different strings.

Comment: No, you are referencing a class attribute of the very same class in all the iterations, so at the end of the loop you end up having updated the very same attribute. You see 10000 different values if you print inside the loop because you are printing the single update on the class attribute (which is overwriting the previous one, for every iteration).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are not creating an instance of your class and you are directly referencing the class attribute `x` of the `test` class. You also have to declare your attributes as instance attributes, hence defining them inside `__init__()`:

```
import string
import random

def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

class test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None

# Create 10000 instances of the test class
lista = [test() for _ in range(10000)]

w = 0
while (w < 10000):
    lista[w].x = id_generator()
    w = w + 1

print(lista[3].x)
print(lista[40].x)
print(lista[1999].x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making three different mistakes:

1. You should use instance attributes, and not class attributes:

   ```
   class test:
       def __init__(self):
           self.x = None
           self.y = None
   ```
2. You should instantiate the `test` class. You should write:

   ```
    d = test()
   ```
3. By writing `[d]*10000` you are actually storing 10000 copies of the same object. Write instead:

   ```
   # notice that you can get rid of the 'd' object
   lista = [test() for i in range(0, 10000)]
   ```